# How to keep datatable in "cache" persistently during 24h?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I need to query sqlserver and keep the result in a datatable to use in subsequent calls during next 24h.
What is the best/easy way to save datatable in "cache" for all this time?

Comment: can you be please more specific ? there are more than one cache...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: would using SQL Server temp tables work in your case?

Comment: @Aristos exactly because there are more than one "something" that I was asking what to use? More specific? If I know the answer I was not doing the question...

Comment: @mjwills System.Runtime.Caching dont guarantee the data is there for 24h. Already tried that and after some time data is cleared...

Comment: @timur Cannot access sqlserver again

Comment: Then @Aristos is right. Depending on tradeoffs you are willing/able to make you would be looking at some sort of cache. To know what they are we need to know at least how big is the data table, do you need it do be shared between multiple processes/threads, does it support updates, what OS are you running etc

Comment: `Already tried that and after some time data is cleared.` Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @Idilio If you ask me what to use, I tell you what I do in this cases, I create a static list, or a static dictionary with my data and I use them on my loops. To not lose the static data I just take care the pool to mane no restarts after some time. The sql server by default use a lot of compilate cashes - if you use the sql server you lose there the data transaction time.

Comment: @mjwills
just used:
Cache.Insert(cacheKey, dtDados, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), TimeSpan.Zero);
and in subsequent queries:
dtDados = (System.Data.DataTable)Cache.Get(cacheKey);
and it works fine for the first 2h to 4h, but at some momment in time it's not anymore in cache

Comment: My guess is that your app pool recycled.

Comment: @mjwills app pool recycle I already ruled out, but app domain recycle I dont know how to check...This is why I mentioned persistently